# how to do i iterate through elements of in std::map<std::string,shared_ptr<A>> in c++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, boost, boost-serialization

how to compare data of 2 maps like

`std::map<std::string,shared_ptr<A>>`  where A is `struct` type. I need to compare after the serialization of data type.

eg.

```
  struct A
 {
     int age;
    std::string name;
 }
```

thanks

Comment: You seem to have two questions. How to iterate through elements of a std::map, and how to compare a std::map after it has been serialized with boost.

Is that correct?

Comment: Is this right for you?: Two maps are equal if they have equal keys and values, the values are equal if either both are `NULL` or the structs are equal, and the structs are equal if all elements are equal?

Comment: my question is only how to compare data of two maps..

Answer (score 2):

To iterate through a map, use an *iterator*:

```
typedef std::map<std::string, shared_ptr<A> >  Container_Type;
Container_Type my_map;
Container_Type::iterator iter;
for (iter = my_map.begin(); iter != my_map.end(); ++iter)
(
  // Do stuff here
}
```

The fields of the map can be accessed by:

```
  std::string key;
  key = iter->first;
  shared_ptr<A> value = iter->second;
```